# Child views of UINavigationController not having navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

When the user clicks a button on a `UIViewController` the system "pushes" a `UINavigationControlle` with 2 child views.

As you can see from the screenshot, I am able to configure the cancel button on the first child but the second child view does not have a navigation bar. Shouldn't the second `UIViewController` also automatically inherit the navigation bar?

Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: I am actually pushing from one UIViewController to another UIViewController. Both 'Add Hub' and 'Search Hub' screens are UIViewControllers. There is only one UINavigationController for both of these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `Navigation Item` from Object Library to your `Search Hubs` Screen.

[image: Navigation Item in Object Library]

A `Title` object will appear in Document Outline

[image: Search Hubs Screen with Navigation bar]

Now you can add custom buttons to `Navigation Bar`

[image: Custom Bar Button Items]

Comment: Martin - thank you - this helps. But could you please help me understand why the Navigation Bar isnt automatically inherited?

Comment: Hey, it is inherited for the whole stack. The Navigation Bar and Navigation Controller are accessible from every ViewController in stack via `self.navigationController?.navigationBar?`